# deleting the same sheet (tab) from multiple google workbooks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Please help!  I'm not script-savvy, but I've managed to piece together a few scripts to help my school district create individualized google sheet workbooks for each student in my district's elementary schools.  We have folders with approximately 150 google sheets workbooks per grade level.  All 150 workbooks in each folder have the same tabs (sheets).  I want to be able to delete a specific tab/sheet from all 150 workbooks in one of the folders.  The container-bound script I was using to delete tabs suddenly stopped working.  It now only deletes the tab for the workbook it is attached to, where just a few weeks ago, it deleted the tab from all 150 workbooks.  I must have inadvertently changed something, but I can't figure out what.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's my script:

```
function onOpen() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
}

function deleteSheets() {
    var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER ID");
    var folderFiles = sourceFolder.getFiles();
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[2];'
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().deleteSheet(source); 
}
```

Comment: Does the sheet you wish to delete have a name?

Comment: "Second" is the name of the sheet I am trying to delete.

Comment: Well now you have two ways to do one is by index and the other is by name.  Personally I would rather do it by name because every sheet has to have a unique name

Answer (score 0):

In your script, it seems that the 3rd sheet of the active Spreadsheet is deleted. And, the files in the specific folder are not used. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. In order to delete the specific sheet (3rd sheet) in each Google Spreadsheet in the specific folder of `FOLDER ID`. How about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function deleteSheets() {
  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER ID");
  var files = sourceFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
    var deleteSheet = ss.getSheets()[2]; // or var deleteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetName");
    if (deleteSheet) {
      ss.deleteSheet(deleteSheet);
    }
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, Spreadsheet files are retrieved from `FOLDER ID` folder. And, the 3rd sheet in each Spreadsheet is deleted.
- If you want to delete the sheet by the sheet name, please modify `var deleteSheet = ss.getSheets()[2];` to `var deleteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetName");`

#### Note:

- In this script, a sheet is deleted from each Spreadsheet. So, as a test of this script, I would like to recommend using a sample Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [getFilesByType(mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfilesbytypemimetype)
- [Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)
- [open(file)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openfile)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who is replying. I so appreciate your time and expertise!!! Both of these suggestions result in the following error: "Exception: Argument cannot be null: sheet" Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: @K.O. Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `Both of these suggestions`, in this case, I'm worried that the 3rd sheet or the sheet name might not be existing in the Spreadsheet. So, I modified the sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: You're modification worked!  I used the [2] option and the "Second" sheet was removed from all of my files!  Thank you so very much!  Have a great evening!

Answer (score 0):

#### Delete Sheets from Spreadsheets by name

```
function dsh(n="Second") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("");
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let f = files.next();
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(f.getId());
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName(n);
    if(sh) {
      ss.deleteSheet(sh);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who is replying.  I so appreciate your time and expertise!!!  Both of these suggestions result in the following error: "Exception: Argument cannot be null: sheet"  Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you provide the name of the sheet in the parameter.  It has to be a string.  I provided a default argument so you can now run it with providing a parameter as lolnd the sheet you wish to delete is name "Second".

Comment: I did add the name of the sheet.  I'm still getting the null error.  I ran it just as you posted (replacing the file ID).  I also tried replacing n in line 8 with "Second".

Comment: I just ran it in a  folder on my account and it works fine

Comment: I'll keep playing with it!  Thank you so much for your time and expertise!  I really appreciate it!   Have a great evening!

Comment: I figured it out!  I had manually deleted the "Second" tab from one of my files.  As long as all of the files have the tile listed in the script (which will be the case when I use it for real and not on a sample set of files), this script works!  Thanks again for your help!